# How to clear search history in 'Artha'?

Tags: 16.04, history

Artha is a dictionary application for Ubuntu. I want to know that is there a way to delete the search history from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more information on how to do this on the developers page - see 
[link](http://artha.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Features#Persistant_History)

> History can also be saved so that if you're interested in having the
>   list of words you learnt newly and to revisit them. Both clearing and
>   aving history data can be done by right-clicking on the query box and
>   selecting the appropriate option.

Comment: Some steps would help in case the link becomes broken or removed.